# Socat Raspberry Pi serial to TCP/IP Problems

Tags: linux, serial-port, raspberry-pi, tcp, socat

I'm trying to connect my PC with serial port of RPi via TCP/IP with socat.

```
socat PTY,link=/dev/ttyAMA0 TCP:127.0.0.1:10001
```

But get a message:

```
socat[3509] E connect(5, AF=2 127.0.0.1:10001, 16): Connection refused
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
socat -v /dev/ttyAMA0 tcp-connect:localhost:10001
```

for more, use help: `socat -h`